# Image Cropping and Resizing

Tags: beginner, image, go

I am building a Go based image processing worker for my web application. I am trying to be idiomatic, but I am new to Go. Any feedback, is appreciated. This program uses bimg to generate 4 square images based on top, left, width, height, which come from a client side cropping library (croppie.js)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "gopkg.in/h2non/bimg.v1"
)

var sizes = [3]int{128, 256, 512}

func resizeImage(img []byte, width int, height int, name string) (err error){
    options := bimg.Options{
        Width: width,
        Height: height,
    }

    var thumb []byte

    thumb, err = bimg.Resize(img, options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(os.Stderr, err)
        return err
    }
    err = bimg.Write(name, thumb)
    return
}

func processImage(top, left, width, height int, filename string) (err error){
    var buffer, original []byte
    var image *bimg.Image
    var fileBaseName = strings.Split(filename, ".")[0]

    buffer, err = bimg.Read(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(os.Stderr, err)
    }

    image = bimg.NewImage(buffer)

    original, err = image.Extract(left, top, width, height)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = bimg.Write(fileBaseName + "_original.jpg", original)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(sizes); i++ {
        size := sizes[i]
        err = resizeImage(original, size, size, fmt.Sprintf(fileBaseName + "_%d.jpg", size))
        if(err != nil){
            log.Println(os.Stderr, err)
            return err
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    err := processImage(50,50,400,400, "test2.jpeg")
    if(err != nil){
        log.Println(os.Stderr, err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All in all this code is decent for a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) attempt at what is actually quite a sophisticated operation. Importing multiple libraries, logging, buffers, etc. Good job on just getting the job done.

There are a number of improvements though that you should consider. There are easier ones, and more complicated ones.

#### Function names

`processImage` is not a great name for a function. You may as well call it `doStuff`.... ;-) Choosing a name that represents the functions activity is a good way to confirm the function is doing just one thing (which is a goal of the [SRP - single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). A name like `extractCropResizes` would be closer, but that shows that the function is doing too many things, it's cropping, and resizing things. Consider splitting it in two, and calling both parts from the parent:

```
func extractCropResizes(....) {
    crop, err := cropImage(....)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    extractResizes(crop, ...)
}
```

#### Globals

As for the actual functionality, it irks me that `sizes` is a global constant. I feel these resizes should be passed in as a variable to the looping resizing function. Globals tend to become problems when things need maintenance.

#### Error handling

Your error handling is incomplete, and inconsistent.

Your function returns an optional error, which is fine, but you're not trapping all the conditions. Consider this code:

> ```
> buffer, err = bimg.Read(filename)
> if err != nil {
>     log.Println(os.Stderr, err)
> }
> ```

If there ***is*** an error in there, you log the error, and then immediately will panic when the next line runs: `image = bimg.NewImage(buffer)` because buffer will be `nil`. Hmmm... I looked at the code, and no, the panic won't happen in the next line, but in the following one when the image is manipulated: [`Extract` code](https://github.com/h2non/bimg/blob/master/image.go#L57).

Now, the consistency is also a problem. You declare the `error` return value to be called `err` in the function declaration: `func processImage(top, left, width, height int, filename string) (err error)`

If you use a named return value, then don't have return values in the return statement.

Also, no need to have a return as the last statement in the block.

Logging some errors to the console, and not others, is also inconsistent.

#### StdErr

Use the standard log functions to set the output destination of log messages `log.SetOutput(os.StdErr)` https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetOutput and then don't use the option in each call.

Comment: “If the function's signature declares result parameters, the function body's statement list must end in a terminating statement.” Don't ask me why the specification mandates this.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use `range`

The loop over sizes doesn't use the loop index, so it can be written more idiomatically using `range`:

```
for _, size := range sizes {
    // ...
}
```

#### Variable declarations

At many places you declare variables at the top of the function. This is neither necessary not recommended. It's best to declare variables right before you need them, not sooner.

Related to this, most functions use a named return value. This can be useful sometimes. But in the posted code, most of the time you return a value explicitly, and only use a parameterless `return` at the end of functions, so you might as well drop the naming and `return nil` where you need it.

Lastly, in `resizeImage` signature, you could shorten `width int, height int` like you already did in other functions.

#### Logging

I don't understand what `os.Stderr` is doing in the calls to `log.Println`. This function will write to standard error the parameters passed to `fmt.Sprintf`. If you want to log to standard error, you can replace `log.Println(os.Stderr, err)` with simply `log.Println(err)`. The `os.Stderr` is not doing anything useful there, I suspect it was a symbol mistake.

#### Formatting

The code doesn't follow the standard at a few places. Run `go fmt` to fix it.